# How to call a non action method by clicking a button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Forgive me if this is a very newby question.

how can i call a method (sharing an object on facebook) when user clicked on the share button in the view.

I can do the share/facebook parts, i just don't know how to call a method from the model when the user clicks on a button

Answer (score 0):

my_controller.rb

```
def do_something
 ...
end
```

routes.rb

```
get "/something" => "my_controller#do_something", :as => :do_something
#you can also use post, put, delete or match instead of get
```

view

```
<%= link_to "call do something", do_something_path %>
```

for post etc...

```
<%= link_to "call do something", do_something_path, method: :post %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential answers depending on your specific needs.

- If you want to add a method to your model outside of the columns you've created for your object you can do so in the model.rb file:

model.rb

```
def name_twice
    "#{self.name}#{self.name}"
end
```

You can then take an instance of a model to call this: "@model.name_twice".

- If you want to add another routed method in the controller, you can define it in your models_controller file:

models_controller.rb

```
def approve
    @model = Model.find_by_id(params[:model_id])
    model.toggle!(:approved)
    redirect_to @model
end
```

In order for the new controller function to work, you must add it in the routes file:

routes.rb

```
resources :models do
   get 'approve', :on => :member 
end
```

Hope this might be a little helpful. These examples should give you an idea of how to add other methods/actions to a model/controller.